# Updating a referenced object in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a singleton object for settings in my project which, through references, I pass on.
Now I use a MVVM approach in my application and only pass a copy of the object to the settings dialog. If the user clicks cancel nothing will ever get updated, but if the user presses OK I want to change the central settings object. If I do

```
(theLocalSettingsObject) = new Settings(... the values from the dialog);
```

the central object won't get updated.

I don't want to set every single property by hand, which however would work.

Comment: If it's a singleton, how come you have copies of it?

Comment: Can you share the line of code that doesn't work?

Comment: Tried AutoMapper? Not by hand.

Comment: @Oded, it is a singleton as in I have one instance of it and access it using MEF.

Comment: If you have copies, it is not a singleton.

Comment: @TomTom I tried AutoMapper like this: Mapper.Map<Settings, Settings>(settingsFromDialog, this.Settings);

Comment: @Oded there are no copies, only references. With the exception of a clone I use only to bind the data to the form. If I didn't to this I'd have to implement somekind of Memento pattern.

Comment: @errorcode007 - If these are indeed references and not copies, a change to the reference would be a change to the "central object".

Comment: @Oded If there is only a single instance of `Settings` in the AppDomain that carries the meaning of "Current Settings" that's pretty singletonish, even if there are instances of the same class that represent unsaved settings. It might not be a singleton in the strict sense, but it's intend is certainly that of a singleton.

Comment: http://hastebin.com/bapexokiro.cs Here's how it's currently happening

Comment: I think he says he has a singleton in the aplpication level, but createsa  copy for editing and then tries to merge the changes back into the single master instance. This allows the dialog to be cancelled without the singleton changing. So, for the "application in general" there is a singleton to get settings, but the dialog makes a copy to edit it. That is how I understand it.

Comment: Now, if I do this: `this.Settings = Mapper.Map<Settings, Settings>(settings, this.Settings);`  only this.Settings will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection. If you pack the code into a generic helper class, you can call like this

```
PropertyUpdater.Update(mainSettings).With(settingsFromDialog);
```

where the helper class looks like this

```
public class PropertyUpdater
{
    public static PropertyUpdater<T> Update<T>(T objectToUpdate)
    {
        return PropertyUpdater<T>.Update(objectToUpdate);
    }
}

public class PropertyUpdater<T>
{
    private readonly T destination;

    private PropertyUpdater(T destination)
    {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public static PropertyUpdater<T> Update(T objectToUpdate)
    {
        return new PropertyUpdater<T>(objectToUpdate);
    }

    public void With(T objectToCopyFrom)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
        {
            // Only copy properties with public get and set methods
            if (!p.CanRead || !p.CanWrite || p.GetGetMethod(false) == null || p.GetSetMethod(false) == null) continue;
            // Skip indexers
            if (p.GetGetMethod(false).GetParameters().Length > 0) continue;

            p.SetValue(this.destination, p.GetValue(objectToCopyFrom, null), null);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

So from `ShellViewModel` that would be

```
private void SaveSettings(Settings settings)
{
    PropertyUpdater.Update(this.Settings).With(settings);
}
```

Here's a passing unit test (MSTest).

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var someClassInstance1 = new ClassA();
        var someClassInstance2 = new ClassA();
        var mainSettings = new Settings
            {
                SomeInt = 1, 
                SomeString = "2", 
                SomeObject = true, 
                SomeClass = someClassInstance1,
                SomeArray = new[] { false }
            };

        var refToMainSettings = mainSettings;

        var dialogSettings = new Settings
            {
                SomeInt = 2,
                SomeString = "3",
                SomeObject = 1.0,
                SomeClass = someClassInstance2,
                SomeArray = new[] { true, false }
            };

        // The magic method :-)
        PropertyUpdater.Update(mainSettings).With(dialogSettings);

        Assert.AreSame(refToMainSettings, mainSettings);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, mainSettings.SomeInt);
        Assert.AreEqual("3", mainSettings.SomeString);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(mainSettings.SomeObject, typeof(double));
        Assert.AreEqual(1.0, mainSettings.SomeObject);
        Assert.AreSame(someClassInstance2, mainSettings.SomeClass);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, mainSettings.SomeArray.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, mainSettings.SomeArray[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual(false, mainSettings.SomeArray[1]);
    }

    public class Settings
    {
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
        public string SomeString { get; set; }
        public object SomeObject { get; set; }
        public ClassA SomeClass { get; set; }
        public bool[] SomeArray { get; set; }
        public bool this[int i]
        {
            get { return SomeArray[i]; }
            set { SomeArray[i] = value; }
        }
    }

    public class ClassA {}
```

Comment: Of course Reflection will be slower than a true private `Settings.SaveSettings(settingsToCopy)` method that copies each property by hand, but if you're dealing with user input, it probably won't be noticeable.

Comment: The `PropertyUpdater` will also copy base class properties.

Comment: This really nice and exactly what I need. Thanks for all the effort!

Comment: yo dog, i heard you like antipatterns

Comment: @AndrewBullock Yo Andrew, I heard you like downvotes. No seriously though, where's the antipattern in my answer? I just answered the general question: is it possible to update the properties of a class instance with another class instance without having to write a `Copy` method that explicitly copies every property in the class? I think that question is a good one, regardless of whether or not errorcode007 uses singletons.

Comment: @AndrewBullock Anyway errorcode007 isn't necessarily suffering from a singleton anti-pattern. Errorcode007 said the settings object is a MEF-injected Shared instance, aka dependency injection's **Singleton lifestyle**, not a singleton design (anti)pattern.

Answer (score 2):

if youre going to use a singleton, then i suggest making it static

```
public static class Settings
{
    public static string Propery { get; set; }
}
```

this way you dont need to pass references about,

you can just access `Settings.Property` from anywhere.

**Edit re your comments**

if youre loading the settings from a database or something, make a static manager instead:

```
public static class SettingsManager
{
    public static Settings Get()
    {
        // get settings from db, memory, wherever
    }
}
```

Comment: That's two steps worse from what the OP is using. It's even worse than a `class.Instance` singleton, and those are bad enough.

Comment: With your edit you pretty much have a `Class.Instance` singleton, which is an incarnation of the service-locator anti-pattern.

Comment: im not promoting singletons, it answers his question in the simplest way and will solve his short term problem. didnt seem worth going in to dependency injection and such wider architectural patterns

Answer (score 0):

I currently have the same scenario as you and I ended with creating a Copy method to copy all the values from the copy settings to the real settings.

I implemented the method calling the properties one by one thou, I don't see any problem with this.

```
realSettings.Copy(tempSettings);
```

Anyway I won't use singletons at all, they are [evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with SoMoS in that singletons (in the way that I've often seen them) are indeed [evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil).  The alternative I would recommend, however, is to harness dependency injection to ensure that everyone has a reference to the same object. Ninject, for instance, has a fluent binding for what it calls "[singleton scope](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes)", where it ensures that the same object for a given type is bound every time an instance is requested.  I have used this particular model extensively and it works great.  You also have the added benefit that the consumers of your "singleton" don't need to know that it's a singleton, they are decoupled, and can be unit tested much easier.

Comment: I'm doing it like this, but I use MEF which has a similar concept (See: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2010/01/09/mef-for-beginner-part-creation-policy-part-6.aspx  about CreationPolicy) But I have the problem that I'd need to set every single property by hand because assigning a Settings object somehow nullifies the reference and make the current settings object an independent one.

Comment: Is your settings object a `struct` instead of a `class`?

Comment: It's a class and decorated with this: `[PartCreationPolicy (CreationPolicy.Shared)]
  [Export("Settings")]` see the following paste for all info please:  http://hastebin.com/yaqefivaxo.cs